# Read Yahoo Chat history on web

Tags: yahoo-messenger

Where is Yahoo IM history location? Yahoo saves history on his server.

Where can I see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Yahoo! Help:

> #### [How to use Yahoo! Mail to access your Yahoo! Messenger 11 Conversation History Archives](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?locale=en_US&page=content&id=SLN651&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1301148736075&y=PROD_MSNG_MSNGWB)
>
> 1. Sign in to [Yahoo! Mail](https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?.intl=us&.src=ym).
> 2. Go to the "Search Mail" box in the Yahoo! Mail page.
> 3. Enter the Yahoo! ID, Name, or string of the conversation that you would like to find in the "Search Mail" box and click Go. The results will be listed in a new tab.
> 4. Once the search is complete, you can use the options under "Narrow Results" on the right side of the page to get more precise results. **NOTE:** You may need to click **Retrieve Refinement Options** in order to see the list to the right.
> 5. Click the **@C@Chats** folder from the options to display all of the Yahoo! Messenger archives.

Comment: For the new Yahoo Messenger clubbed with the yahoo mail service, you can go this for accessing : https://messenger.yahoo.com/archive/